# How to add ArrayList parameter to an ArrayList then then add to current class ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have an ArrayList called Service that accepts an enum ServiceType, a double price, and an ArrayList Employee.

I'm trying to create a method that adds a service element to the Service ArrayList but I'm getting an error stating

Service() in Service cannot be applied to Expected parameters Actual Arguments
serviceName: serviceType serviceName
price double price new Employee(mechanicName) (Employee)

I have tried creating the ArrayList object for Employee inside the Service ArrayList object and then adding it to the Transactions ArrayList but that is not working.

///Transactions class

```
public class Transaction {
    private ArrayList<Service> services;

    public Transaction() {
        this.services = new ArrayList<Service>();
    }

    
    public boolean createNewService(ServiceType serviceName, double price,
                                    Employee mechanic, String mechanicName){
        Service existingService = findService(serviceName, price, mechanic);
        if(existingService == null){

            this.services.add(new Service(serviceName, price, new Employee(mechanicName)));
        }
        return false;
    }

    
    private Service findService(ServiceType serviceName, double price,
                                Employee machanic){
        for(int i=0; i<this.services.size(); i++){
            Service chkdServise = this.services.get(i);
            if(this.services.get(i).getServiceName().equals(serviceName) &&
            this.services.get(i).getPrice() == price &&
            this.services.get(i).getMachanics().equals(machanic)){
                return chkdServise;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

///Service Class

```
public class Service {
    private ServiceType serviceName;
    private double price; 
    private ArrayList<Employee> machanics;


    public Service(ServiceType serviceName, double price) {
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
        this.price = price;
        this.machanics = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    }

public boolean createEmployee(String name){
        Employee existingEmployee = findEmployee(name);
        if(existingEmployee == null){
            this.machanics.add(new Employee(name));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    private Employee findEmployee(String name){
        for(int i=0; i<machanics.size(); i++){
            Employee chkedEmployee = this.machanics.get(i);
            if(this.machanics.get(i).getName().equals(name)){
                return chkedEmployee;
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
```

///Employee Class

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private int salary;


    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = 50000;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }


    }
```

Comment: can you show the complete error stack trace. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your code. But the most important one that is causing the error is, you have a constructor for your `Service` which accepts only two parameters `ServiceType` and `price`, but you are trying to pass in three parameters in your `Transaction` class. What you need is :

```
    public boolean createNewService(ServiceType serviceName, double price,
                                    Employee mechanic, String mechanicName){
        Service existingService = findService(serviceName, price, mechanic);
        if(existingService == null){
            Service newService = new Service(serviceName, price);
            newService.createEmployee(new Employee(mechanicName));
            this.services.add(newService);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

You see that I changed code to pass in two parameters only for the `Service` object which is what is needed by its constructor. And then used `createEmployee` method you already have in your `Service` class. And then add the new service to the list of services.

Other minor improvements ( *that I could find* ):

1. `findService` method

```
private Service findService(ServiceType serviceName, double price,
                            Employee machanic) {
    for(int i=0; i<this.services.size(); i++) {
        Service chkdServise = this.services.get(i);
        if(chkdServise.getServiceName().equals(serviceName) &&
        chkdServise.getPrice() == price &&
        chkdServise.getMachanics().equals(machanic)){
            return chkdServise;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

See that you don't need to use `this.services.get(i)` everytime. You already got it once in `chkdServise`.

2. Similar improvement with `findEmployee`:

```
private Employee findEmployee(String name){
        for(int i=0; i<machanics.size(); i++){
            Employee chkedEmployee = this.machanics.get(i);
            if(chkedEmployee.getName().equals(name)){
                return chkedEmployee;
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is mismatch in the constructor arguments of Service class. What IDE what are using? You should have got the error at the compilation step.

Comment: I'm using Intellij. Thanks, I probably did get one but I'm learning java and I dont think I understood the error that what shown.